# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Deploying Worklight to external Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing a Worklight (v6.0) application. I have added Tomcat server in Eclipse server perspective. With that I have deployed my application, and it is working fine.

I want know, how can we deploy our application in an external apache server? i.e without adding Tomcat server in Eclipse.

Comment: Is this question resolved? Please mark as Answered.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have another instance of Apache Tomcat installed on your computer - simply download and extract it somewhere in your hard disk.

You need to then "install" to it the Worklight framework files and prepare databases based on your worklight.properties setup.

Then you need to simply deploy your project's .war file to it (can be found in the bin folder in your Worklight project), followed by deploying your .adapter files and application .wlapp files (also found in the bin folder).

Assuming you are an IBM Worklight customer, then after extracting Tomcat in your HD, you can and should use the IBM Installation Manager and Ant task scripts to handle the rest (deploying Worklight framework, setting up the database, deploying the .war file).

See this topic in the IBM Worklight 6.0 Information Center:

- [Installing Worklight Server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_installation.html)

If you prefer to work manually...:

- [Deploying a project WAR file and configuring the application server manually](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_manually_configuring_app_server.html)

Note that the Worklight framework .jar file is available ONLY to customers of IBM Worklight.